# Tasks: exceptions and cancelation

Tags: c#, task, .net-4.5

I need to do a long running task. I've done this by executing a Task while there's a loading box on the UI. When an exception is thrown, I want to stop the task and show a msgbox to the user. If everything goes right, I stop the loading box.

The code below works as expected, but I was wondering if I'm doing it correct here since this is the first time I'm doing somehting like this.

```
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    protected void ProgramImage()
    {
        this.OnProgrammingStarted(new EventArgs());
        var task =
            Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ProgramImageAsync)
                .ContinueWith(
                    this.TaskExceptionHandler,
                    cancellationTokenSource.Token,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
                    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())  //Catch exceptions here
                        .ContinueWith(
                            o => this.ProgramImageAsyncDone(),
                            cancellationTokenSource.Token,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
                            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());  //Run this when no exception occurred
    }

    private void ProgramImageAsync()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Actual programming is done here
        throw new Exception("test");
    }

    private void TaskExceptionHandler(Task task)
    {
        var exception = task.Exception;
        if (exception != null && exception.InnerExceptions.Count > 0)
        {
            this.OnProgrammingExecuted(
                new ProgrammingExecutedEventArgs { Success = false, Error = exception.InnerExceptions[0] });
            this.Explanation = "An error occurrred during the programming.";
        }
        // Stop execution of further taks
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void ProgramImageAsyncDone()
    {
        this.OnProgrammingExecuted(new ProgrammingExecutedEventArgs { Success = true });
        this.Explanation = ResourceGeneral.PressNextBtn_Explanation;
        this.IsStepComplete = true;
    }
```

The event `OnProgrammingStarted` shows the loading box on the UI thread.
The event `OnProgrammingExecuted` stops this loading box and shows a message whether or not the programming was done successfuly.
Both have the UI-thread as a subscriber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked this question also on *Code Review* because here wasn't exactly the right place for it. 
For those who stumble upon this question and would like to know the answer: [you can find it here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27021/tasks-exceptions-and-cancelation)